# Magento 2 Fail to save the value of a newly added Yes/No customer attribute

Tags: magento2, eav, customer-attribute, save

The customer attribute shows up but cannot save it because there are no records about this attribute in eav_entity_attribute table, when I manually add a row for the attribute, it can be saved. How to deal with it? What was missed? Thanks.

```
namespace Namespace\ModuleName\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetup;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface {

    /**
     * Customer setup factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    private $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(\Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }


    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context) {

        $setup->startSetup();

        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(
                Customer::ENTITY, 'abc', [
            'label' => 'ABC',
            'input' => 'select',
            'type' => 'int',
            'default' => false,
            'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
            'user_defined' => true,
            'required' => true,
            'position' => 82,
            'sort_order' => 82,
            'visible' => true,
            'system' => false,
            'is_used_in_grid' => true,
            'is_visible_in_grid' => true,
            'is_filterable_in_grid' => true,
            'is_searchable_in_grid' => true,
                ]
        );

        $customerSetup->updateAttribute('customer', 'myhkt', 'is_used_for_customer_segment', '1');

        // add attribute to form
        /** @var  $attribute */

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer', 'abc');
        $attribute->setData('used_in_forms', ['adminhtml_customer']);
        $attribute->save();
        $setup->endSetup();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 9):

I found the answer finally.
adding:

```
   $attributeMyhkt->addData([
                'attribute_set_id' => 1,
                'attribute_group_id' => 1
            ]);
```

below:

```
 $attribute->setData('used_in_forms', ['adminhtml_customer']);
```